# Empty space at the bottom of a one photo web page

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the empty space at the botton of this webpage please?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body style="margin:0px;">

    <img src="home.jpg" border="0" width="5334" height="4370" orgWidth="5334" orgHeight="4370" usemap="#exhib" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    <map name="exhib" id="">
    <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="4424,122,4537,237"/>
    <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="4550,124,4663,239"/>
    </map>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're link gives a 404!

Comment: It is not giving 404 for me. But I cannot see the empty space.

Comment: @Anar There is no empty space anymore. The problem was resolved. Thank you all!

Comment: Dude, it's not a web page, it's just a [big honking image](http://www.exhibarazi.org/)! You could make it fill the browser window, but it would be distorted. A better option for getting an image to fill the body is to give the `html/body` `height: 100%` and then use a bg image with `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you must add `display: block` to the image.